# Pandas: Set specific columns to 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with a single row.  I want to simultaneously add a list of columns, called `new_cols`, and set all of their values to 0.

Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

My attempt:

`article_features[new_cols] = 0` but that doesn't work :(

Thanks!

Comment: What is the data type of `new_cols`?

Comment: @DYZ It's a string

Comment: Where does the _list_ come from, then?

Comment: Please include a sample value of `new_cols` and the exact error message.

Comment: @DYZ Sorry, I was wrong: `new_cols` has a bunch of unicode in it

Comment: @bclayman, can you post an output of `print(new_cols)` in your question?

Comment: Unicode or string, same difference. But is `new_cols` a list of strings or one strings? If it is one string, where do other column names come from?

Comment: printing `new_cols[:10]` gives us `[u'utpica', u'cityvia', u'lostncheeseland', u'programcontribute', u'vang', u'deflatedlike', u'nunnery', u'vivemos', u'withamachete', u'gah']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pd.DataFrame.reindex_axis` and the `fill_value=0` parameter.

```
df.reindex_axis(df.columns.union(new_cols), axis=1, fill_value=0)

   a  b  c  c1  c2  c3
0  1  2  3   0   0   0
1  4  5  6   0   0   0
```

Or for strings use `fill_value='0'`

```
df.reindex_axis(df.columns.union(new_cols), 1, fill_value='0')

   a  b  c c1 c2 c3
0  1  2  3  0  0  0
1  4  5  6  0  0  0
```

---

**Setup**
I borrowed objects from @MaxU

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 4], 'b': [2, 5], 'c': [3, 6]})
new_cols = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `assign` method.

Demo:

```
In [43]: df
Out[43]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

In [44]: new_cols
Out[44]: ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
```

**Option 1:**

```
In [46]: df = df.assign(**{c:0 for c in new_cols})

In [47]: df
Out[47]:
   a  b  c  c1  c2  c3
0  1  2  3   0   0   0
1  4  5  6   0   0   0
```

**Option 2:**

```
In [106]: df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(0, df.index, new_cols))

In [107]: df
Out[107]:
   a  b  c  c1  c2  c3
0  1  2  3   0   0   0
1  4  5  6   0   0   0
```

adding **string** values:

```
In [49]: df = df.assign(**{c:'0' for c in new_cols})

In [50]: df
Out[50]:
   a  b  c c1 c2 c3
0  1  2  3  0  0  0
1  4  5  6  0  0  0

In [51]: df.dtypes
Out[51]:
a      int64
b      int64
c      int64
c1    object
c2    object
c3    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: The OP claims `new_cols` is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can add columns in a loop:

```
for col in new_cols:
    df[col] = 0
```